# iOS - Firebase Filter query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got score node in Firebase:

And under score node my data structure is as:

```
{
"jjTO29ziQ2SjrH5PFzY7ZMpSgjq1-Kak6FCyGtdy_kcEPd4K" =     {
    jjTO29ziQ2SjrH5PFzY7ZMpSgjq1 = "-Kak6FCyGtdy_kcEPd4K";
    score = 5;
};
"jjTO29ziQ2SjrH5PFzY7ZMpSgjq1-KbE_pgfUsukOm4uW0bx" =     {
    jjTO29ziQ2SjrH5PFzY7ZMpSgjq1 = "-KbE_pgfUsukOm4uW0bx";
    score = 4;
};
```

**Question:**
**Can I filter the data by score ?**

I tried doing :

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("scores").queryOrdered(byChild: "score").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        debugPrint(snapshot.value ?? "nil")

    })
```

But can't get the result ?

[image: Picture 1]

Comment: You Can filter by data with orderByChild but I think your problem is because you haven entered the corresponding nodes that have score inside. Because you are entering score at the beginning as a child, but first you need to enter to each of your id`s.

Comment: What is the problem? Does the `debugPrint` get called?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios : I have my node set up as in picture 1 ?
Can you suggest any ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: yeah debug print is called but the data is not sorted by score

Comment: But did you get what I say? You are entering scores and then filtering by score, and scores doesn't have a direct child named score, it has 2 different childs that inside of them there is a value called score.

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios: yep you are right I got no direct child named score.

I have to filter . Can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can! I think the answer below is correct. (Frank van Puffelen)

Answer (score 6):

When you execute a query against Firebase, you get a `FIRDataSnapshot` that contains three pieces of information for each result:

- its key
- its value
- its position relative to other nodes

When you're calling `snapshot.value` the snapshot is converted into a Dictionary. Unfortunately that dictionary can only hold key-value pairs, so you lose the information on the position of the nodes. So while the data in the snapshot is actually sorted correctly, you're throwing that information away.

The solution is to use the `FIRDataSnapshot`s built-in `children` property to loop over the child nodes in the correct order. The [Firebase documentation on querying](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) has this sample of how to do that:

```
_commentsRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
})
```