# How OrderBy in Firebase Database with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `Database` with the `Ranking` of my Game. I trying to get the most **high score players**.

I trying to `order by` `score`. I tried some different queries but it doesn't ordering! It returns all the elements but not **ordered**.
What should I do?

**Code**:

```
Database.database().reference().child("ranking")
                               .queryOrdered(byChild: "score")
                               .observe(.value, with: {
        (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            let ranking = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

            for rankingPlayer in ranking {
                let player = rankingPlayer.value
                print(player)
            }
        })
```

**Database:**

[image: database]

**PS:** Why not order after got the **snapshot** result? Because I will have thousands of scores and I will just limit my query to the ten biggest high scores.

Comment: You're converting the `DataSnapshot` (which contains information about the order of items) to a dictionary (which is implicitly unordered). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41851185/209103

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen it worked perfectly !!